# Do something (show message) when all emails have been processed by a macro

Tags: vba, outlook

Edit:

I have a macro written to process an email. By selecting multiple emails and  hitting the macro button, it'll run it sequentially on every selected email. I'd like to show a message in outlook once all the emails have been processed.

Comment: [`MsgBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251821%28v=office.14%29.aspx)?

Comment: It would be beneficial to you to learn how to break problems down into simple pieces that you can conquer. In this case, the fact that you are processing emails has nothing to do with the problem. And the now-reduced problem of ["show message from vba"](https://www.google.com/search?q=show%20message%20from%20vba) is very easily answered with a quick Google search.

Comment: Not sure if I've explained it enough. Msgbox would display message after each processed email. I want to show message after macro has been run on last processed email.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are interested in the [SyncEnd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff866270(v=office.15).aspx) event. It is fired immediately after Microsoft Outlook finishes synchronizing a user’s folders using the specified Send/Receive group.

```
Dim WithEvents mySync As Outlook.SyncObject 

Sub Initialize_handler() 
   Set mySync = Application.Session.SyncObjects.Item(1) 
   mySync.Start 
End Sub  
Private Sub mySync_SyncEnd() 
    MsgBox "Synchronization is complete." 
End Sub
```